# Counting the number of cells which contain a specific character

Tags: numbers, iwork

I want to count the number of cells which contain the character “1” in an Apple Numbers table row. When the row of cells include (using a space delimiter between cells),

```
1234  5671 1 8765 6113 2468
```

I want it to return a 4, because that is how many cells contain a character “1” in the row.

- `COUNTIF(B9:J9,“~1”)` returns a 0.
- `COUNTIF(B9:J9,“=1”)` returns a 1.
- `COUNTIF(B9:J9,“*1”)` returns a 0.
- `COUNTIF(B9:J9,“?1”)` returns a 0.
- `COUNTIF(B9:J9,“=”&(1))` returns the number of blank cells.
- `COUNTIF(B9:J9,“=*1*”)` returns a 0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

A glitch in the `COUNTIF` functions prevents it from working with numbers.  This could be easily fixed by the Excel function `TEXT()` but Numbers doesn't have that function. So...

To solve select B9:J9 and change the `Data Format`, in the `Cell` submenu, from Automatic to `Text`. Then use the function `=COUNTIF(B9:J9,”*1*”)` to count the amount containing the number.

Screenshot showing formula when cells formatted as text:

[image: Screenshot showing formula]

Setting the cell format to text:

[image: Settings for format text]

Comment: @bjbk Good edit. Was going to add images but was too lazy :)

Comment: It's a great answer.  My test was based on a row of phone numbers I had in a spare sheet, which are naturally formatted as text, that's what I get for being hasty.  ;)